# Convert Python function into Objective-C?

Tags: python, ios, objective-c

I am trying to decrypt a YouTube signature parameter. I have found something, but I am not able to understand what I've found so far.

Here is the Python function:

```
if len(s) == 92:
    return s[25] + s[3:25] + s[0] + s[26:42] + s[79] + s[43:79] + s[91] + s[80:83]
elif len(s) == 90:
    return s[25] + s[3:25] + s[2] + s[26:40] + s[77] + s[41:77] + s[89] + s[78:81]
elif len(s) == 88:
    return s[48] + s[81:67:-1] + s[82] + s[66:62:-1] + s[85] + s[61:48:-1] + s[67] + s[47:12:-1] + s[3] + s[11:3:-1] + s[2] + s[12]
elif len(s) == 87:
    return s[4:23] + s[86] + s[24:85]
elif len(s) == 86:
    return s[2:63] + s[82] + s[64:82] + s[63]
elif len(s) == 85:
    return s[2:8] + s[0] + s[9:21] + s[65] + s[22:65] + s[84] + s[66:82] + s[21]
elif len(s) == 84:
    return s[83:36:-1] + s[2] + s[35:26:-1] + s[3] + s[25:3:-1] + s[26]
elif len(s) == 83:
    return s[6] + s[3:6] + s[33] + s[7:24] + s[0] + s[25:33] + s[53] + s[34:53] + s[24] + s[54:]
elif len(s) == 82:
    return s[36] + s[79:67:-1] + s[81] + s[66:40:-1] + s[33] + s[39:36:-1] + s[40] + s[35] + s[0] + s[67] + s[32:0:-1] + s[34]
elif len(s) == 81:
    return s[6] + s[3:6] + s[33] + s[7:24] + s[0] + s[25:33] + s[2] + s[34:53] + s[24] + s[54:81]
```

How can I convert the above Python function into an Objective-C function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It should be pretty easy, but I will not do your work entirely, instead I will explain how the brackets work in Python.**

If we assume that `s` is a `string`, `s[x]` returns the character at X.

```
s = 'some long string'
print s[3]
```

Prints out:

```
e
```

So to write this in Objective-C:

```
NSString* s = @"some long string";
NSLog (@"%@", [s substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 1)]);
```

For the next try, we have `s[x:y]`

```
print s[3:7]
```

This will print out:

```
e lo
```

To write this in Objective-C, we again use the `substringWithRange` method.

```
NSLog (@"%@", [s substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 4)]);
```

Only we must be careful to do some calculation, because NSMakeRange takes length as a parameter, not second index.

And for the last one, we have: `s[x:y:z]`

```
print s[3:7:2]
```

This will print out:

```
e
```

It only takes two characters from 3, so **e and space**.

**The + operator just concatenates strings.**

Read how strings are done in Python here:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm
- http://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/

And read `NSString` documentation on [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-10850).

*Of course you need to wrap those statements in switch or IF-ELSEIF clauses to make the function behave the same as the one in Python. All you have here is basic string manipulation, which you should be able to do yourself, not ask others to do it instead of you.*

Comment: Thanks man your explanation is superb helpful for me. thanks againg

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way way to do it would be change if/elif to switch/case. it would be something like that:

```
 switch (s.length)
 {
     case 92:
          //something something
          break;
     case 90:
          //something something
          break;
     default:
          break;
 }
```

and each of "returns" you have to manage individually. Python array slicing means for example that in string s[3:6] you get substring starting on 3rd letter and ending on 4th. In objective-C you can use substringFromIndex: